# AttributeError: module 'pandora' has no attribute 'util'

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, architecture

I have a github repo named pandora:

https://github.com/akshkr/pandora-python

In the `test_case_refactor` branch, I can't use submodules of pandora such as `pn.util.misc.seed_everything()` gives me the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'pandora' has no attribute 'util'
```

I doubted circular imports so moved every import inside function wherever possible but didn't seem to work. And the test-cases written inside the module are passing.

Can someone tell me what exact issue is causing this AttributeError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `misc` is a python script and not a module in itself, you need to either import the function itself

```
from pandora.util.misc import seed_everything
seed_everything()
```

OR, you can import the `misc` script from `util` module

```
from pandora.util import misc
misc.seed_everything()
```